# A better way to get the rendered view code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to send some html code to another site via API on my rails 2.3 application.
The html code is rendered by another action.
Is there a good way for a controller to get the rendered view html code?

One way I can think of is that action A calls action B via HTTP and get the result.
However, I think this is a waste of resources.
Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want render_to_string which will send the output of the render to a string, instead of back to the client. Use it in your format.js response block.

See [api doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string)

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render(:partial => 'some_thing.html.erb', :layout => false) }
end
```

Comment: sure about this? I believe that render is a special method for ActionController which causes a response back to the client. It doesn't return the content of the response.